# Allow users to edit documents in the library but disable edit page for members

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, site, team-sites

Is there a way to hide the Edit page option from a Teams Site for site members. I still want users to edit documents in the document library.

I tried changing the permissions but it removes all editing options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot achieve this by changing permissions at site level.

You need to break permissions inheritance on "Site Pages" library and then grant "Read" access to group instead of "Edit" access.

Go to "Site Pages" library in SharePoint site and follow steps given in this article: [How to Grant Access to a Document Library in SharePoint Online?](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2020/04/set-permission-to-document-library-in-sharepoint-online.html)